# In a special case, Python's try and except blocks both seem to be evaluated

Tags: python

I have a simple Python code with a try block that opens a file if it exists and prints a message (M!) and exits if it doesn't exist. The except block prints a different message (M2). For some unknown reason, it prints both M1 and M2. Here is the code being executed through an interactive client but the same result is seen even when executed in non-interactive mode:-

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Feb  7 2020, 04:54:24)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isfile("test.txt")
False
>>> try:
...     if os.path.isfile("test.txt"):
...             open("test.txt")
...     else:
...             print("file not found")
...             sys.exit()
... except:
...     print("something else went wrong")
...
file not found
something else went wrong
```

Please let me know if someone could decipher what is going on?

Comment: Hint: `sys.exit` raises an exception…

Comment: @deceze thanks. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sys.exit` exits by raising a `SystemExit` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), which your bare `except` block catches. This is the reason you should never have a bare `except` block, but always `except Exception` (or an even more specific exception). `SystemExit` is not in the [`Exception` hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) and can thus bypass it. Also: [add logging statements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.exception) to see *what* caused the exception you caught.

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed my code by modifying it to the following:-
`except SystemExit:
  pass
except:
  print("something else went wrong")`

Comment: No, do `except Exception`. You're still catching the `SystemExit` exception and drop it, which you should never do unless you have a good reason to (which you don't).

Answer (score 1):

The `try` block is executed up until an exception is thrown. When that happens, the `except` block executes. So in this case, an exception is thrown some time after `"file not found"` is printed. You can investigate this further by catching the exception explicitly:

```
try:
    print("some message")
    sys.exit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```